# "safebrowsing" flag doesn't work anymore with latest chromedriver version 93.0.4577.1500 in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using chromedriver with selenium using C# and I used to add **"options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing", "enabled");"** to options object and everything has been perfect(since  almost a year now) until a couple of days ago chrome browser had an update version **93.0.4577.63** so I had to update chrome driver to version **93.0.4577.1500**, when I tried to run the scripts, I got this error:

**OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)**

**Note: The error goes away when I remove the option: **options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing", "enabled");****

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why, but it worked when I changed `AddUserProfilePreference` method arguments to be like this `options.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");`.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.